# Extracting .bz2 file on Windows creates a single file with no extension, how do i open it?

Tags: linux, windows, bzip2

I have no idea what kind of file this is, if i open it in Notepad ++ first few strings look like this:

Layer 0
 0
 true
 false
 false
 true
 false
 wmNone
 0
 0

Answer (score 1):

Because the `bzip2` utility compresses only a single file (or stream), an additional container is required. This would usually be a `.tar` file, hence the extension `.tar.bz2` or `.tbz2` for short.

So it’s probably a `.tar` archive. Because it’s not compressed in any way, you can see what’s inside. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will recognize and open this archive type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately 7-zip is not recognising single extracted file as archive.

Comment: In that case it’s probably not an archive. What was the original file name (before extracting) and what is it supposed to be anyway?

Comment: File name before extracting is "Guy.bz2". After i extract it i got a single file names "Guy" with no extension. I would be really gratefull if some one can extract those files and upload them (maybe on google disc or similar storage)? I dont have a linux machine around unfortunately.Here is the file, 6 mb : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1vtPJubPyb8cmdveUJxQmNyNDg/view?usp=sharing After extracting it is suppose to be a bunch of files from 3D graphics applications,

Comment: Based on the XML contained, the file may be for Maya.

Comment: Daniel, files are Obj files and couple of 3dcoat files, OBJ files have traveled throu a bunch of applications, Maya included. If it is possible, can you be so kind and upload the files if you was able to extract them?

Comment: I didn’t do anything special. Like you already noticed, it’s a single compressed file called `Guy`. I simply looked at the contents with a text editor. It’s a binary file, though. It does certainly contain OBJ data at the end, but there’s much more inside, some XML and probably some images.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for explanation. Is it possible to extract this data to separate files? Return it to pre-pack state?

Comment: This data is not packed in a common archive format. You’ll need to contact the author.